# hiden pasaporte y cedula select

Tags: php

Quisiera que cuando la persona seleccione pasaporte cambie o se esconda donde va  el numero cedula y aparezca el numero de pasaporte y que también  si se puede almacenar en el mismo campo donde va la cedula para no hacer una nueva columna en la base de datos que diga pasaporte porque ya llevo rato intentándolo y a veces me guarda y a veces no en la base de datos y ya no se que hacer mas para poder corregirlo. O agregarle cosas o quitarle.

(Postdata: Le quite algunos `div` para que le código no sea tan largo)

[image: mi ventana]

```
    <?php
if ($_GET['id']) {
    $cliente = $clienteNegocio->recuperar($_GET['id']);
    $txtAction = 'Editar';          
}else{
    $cliente = new cliente();
    $txtAction = 'Agregar';
}

?>
<script>
function mostrar(id) {
    if (id =="Cedula") {
        $("#Cedula").show();
        $("#Pasaporte").hide();
        
    }
    
    if (id == "Pasaporte") {
        $("#Cedula").hide();
        $("#Pasaporte").show();
        
    }
}
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1><?php echo $txtAction; ?> Cliente</h1>
  </div>
  
    <form role="form" method="post" id="principal">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $cliente->getId();?>" >
        
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $cliente->getNombre();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="apellido">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo $cliente->getApellido();?>" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label for="tipoDoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tipoDoc" name="tipoDoc"  onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
                <option value="Cedula"  <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Cedula') {echo "selected";} ?>  >Cedula</option>
                <option value="Pasaporte" <?php if($cliente->getTipoDoc() == 'Pasaporte') {echo "selected";} ?> >Pasaporte</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id=Cedula class="form-group col">
        <!-- Aquí el método onKeyPress se usa para verificar si la entrada es un número
            en <input type = "number" /> no se puede establecer maxLength
            por lo tanto, debe establecer <input type = "text" />-->
            <label for="nroDoc">Numero de Documento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nroDoc" maxlength=10 name="nroDoc" placeholder="Numero de Documento" value="<?php echo $cliente ->getNroDoc();?>"require>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div id=Pasaporte class="form-group col" >
            <label for="nroDoc">pasaporte</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nroDoc" name="nroDoc" placeholder="Numero de Pasaporte" value="<?php echo $cliente ->getNroDoc();?>"require>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      

        <div class="form-group col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancelForm">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $txtAction; ?></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: No hay error quiero que dependiendo lo que escoja sea cédula o pasaporte aparezca un cuadro o el otro y si e s posible que se guarde las 2 en la misma columna de la base de datos

Comment: ¿Estas usando jQuery?

Comment: Por qué no trabajas con un solo `textBox`? Solo debería ir Número de documento y el valor guardas en la columna ya sea pasaporte o cédula.

Comment: @Bicho tiene razón puedes hacer eso y en todo caso si lo que quieres es validar la longitud y/o formato, puedes poner un evento que tome el valor del select en cuanto cambie y en base a eso validar. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que hice fue que con el script que esta hay cuando escoje cédula se oculta pasaporte y viceversa pero el error radica que cuando quiero guardar en la base de datos no me deja quiero guardar todo en la misma columna pero aveces me deja y aveces no se si estará mal algún parámetro en los div de pasaporte y nrodoc

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea que los ID's de tus div's no están entre comillas
Cambia esto:

```
<div id=Cedula class="form-group col">
```

por esto:

```
<div id="Cedula" class="form-group col">
```

al igual que este:

```
<div id=Pasaporte class="form-group col" >
```

por esto:

```
<div id="Pasaporte" class="form-group col" >
```